# C # Socket - How to detect if my client has lost connection

Tags: c#, sockets

I have an app client that connects to a server socket, I have a function that detects when a disconnection occurs:

```
public static class SocketExtensions
{
    public static bool IsConnected(this Socket socket)
    {
        try
        {
            return !(socket.Poll(1, SelectMode.SelectRead) && socket.Available == 0);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            Trace.Exception(ex, true);
            return false; 
        }
    }
}
```

But sometimes this function does not detect the disconnection and I keep sending packets but the server does not response (every 5 seconds I send polling messages):

```
12:04.40.079 ; polling ================>    3|11111 ; 
12:04.45.087 ; polling ================>    3|11111 ; 
12:04.50.094 ; polling ================>    3|11111 ; 
12:04.55.102 ; polling ================>    3|11111 ; 
12:05.00.109 ; polling ================>    3|11111 ;
```

Normally, I send a message and receive another:

```
12:11.03.730 ; polling ================>    3|11111 ; 
12:11.03.746 ; received <================   4|11111 ;
```

I have to close and runs again my app to establish the communication again.

how to detect if I lost connection to the server?

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the word you want is "polling" rather than "pooling".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send a keep alive packet to detect if you have lost the connection to server, IF you send a packet to server but don't receive back a packet from server that doesn't mean you have lost the connection , You have to check if there is another error in server side or an error in client side , Debug your server to see if you receive a packet from client ,  and IF you receive a packet from client then your connectioin is not lost , it's still alive.

Comment: You're right, the problem is that I can not debug the server, is another system.
Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you create the server yourself ?

Comment: IF the  problem  is in Server side , then you have no other way to fix this problem without checking your server, IF the server is not sending data , then client can do nothing to fix it.  IF the server receives data that you send it means the connection is alive.  IF your client receives nothing , it means the server is not sending data, you have to debug the server to fix this issue

Comment: Why don't you attach a remote debugger to your Server ? , then you can debug your server though it's in another system.

Comment: IF you want to know about remote debugging then check this link  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269663/how-to-programmatically-launch-debugger-in-a-remote-machine/17269735#17269735